# How do I get data from weather.gov through my nftables firewall?

Tags: debian, python, nftables

I'm writing a python script that grabs data from weather.gov (the NDFD SOAP service and current observations XML) to draw a screensaver picture. The script works on my regular computer but not on my pi zero w, which leads me to believe nftables might be blocking the traffic.

When I run the script on my pi, it hangs. When I stop the script by keyboard interrupt, it gives me this traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "makeimage.py", line 121, in <module>
    weather = fetch_weather(latitude, longitude, current_observations_url)
  File "makeimage.py", line 78, in fetch_weather
    weather_xml = minidom.parseString(urllib.request.urlopen(current_observations_url).read())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 517, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 534, in _open
    result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1389, in https_open
    return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPSConnection, req,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in do_open
    h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1255, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1301, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1250, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1010, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 950, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 1417, in connect
    super().connect()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/http/client.py", line 921, in connect
    self.sock = self._create_connection(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/socket.py", line 831, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
```

If this is a firewall issue, how do I tell nftables to accept these connections?

Comment: unless you've specifically added some nft rules yourself, the pi comes with absolutely none. So, please add the `nft list ruleset` results that you believe are blocking the connection

Comment: Well, in the input chain I have `ct state established,related counter packets 165360 bytes 88672036 accept`, but later in the chain I also have `counter packets 59889 bytes 7449570 drop`. the rest are all for ports that local network devices use to talk to each other.

Comment: Sure, I have that too, doesn't stop outgoing connections - what do you use to create those rules? can you disable firewalling on the pi altogether and see if your code works? If that helps, then the issue is with your firewall settings on the pi

Comment: I just type the rules into the command line. I've tried disabling the nftables.service and it hasn't made a difference. If it's not the firewall, I'm not sure what to do.

Comment: `I've tried disabling the nftables.service` did you reboot after disabling the service? did you check `nft list ruleset` after, to confirm there's nothing? can you ping the server you are trying to get data from?

Comment: Well, I've disabled nftables and rebooted the device... and it refuses to access anything that isn't on the local network. Now I'm even more confused.

Comment: perhaps your wifi router is the issue

Comment: is the version of python and its installed components identical on both systems? It doesn't really follow that the issue is firewall based on the info you've provided, unless you are seeing logs of packets being dropped to/from the specific IP address you are trying to connect to. do you get the documents if you use wget or curl, or even a local browser? if it is only the script thats affected, its not firewall, and I'd start debugging by copying the network request processing code to a test stub so you can run it without all the rest of the code.

Comment: It's an identical Python setup, I made sure of it. When I try to ping weather.gov, I get 100% packet loss. When I curl it, I get some HTML. That's interesting.

Comment: ping is unimportant as long as you can connect to the TCP ports the server is hosted on. that curl is able to retrieve the document discounts the firewall a a likely cause.

Answer (score 0):

### Solution 1: wget

What worked at first was to use a workaround: Instead of obtaining the data via Python requests, I used `wget` to download the data to my chosen filenames and had my Python script read those files for the data. Not exactly what I wanted to do, but it worked at least.

Example bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/bash
wget -O /var/www/forecast.xml "http://graphical.weather.gov/xml/SOAP_server/ndfdSOAPclientByDay.php?whichClient=NDFDgenByDay&lat=40.71&lon=-74.00&format=12+hourly&numDays=1&Unit=e"
python3 /var/www/makeimage.py
```

### Solution 2: timeouts

After a long while of fiddling around on my pi, I found that only the requests to IPv6 addresses were failing, and it always tried to contact these addresses first. I naively assumed that python requests had a default timeout length... they don't. So if my pi couldn't contact those IPv6 addresses, it would hang forever. Once I added 5 second timeouts, the code ran slowly but it completed requests and generated the image as planned.

Example python:

```
#with import requests
requests.get(current_observations_url, timeout=5)

#with import zeep
transport = zeep.transports.Transport(timeout=5)
soap_client = zeep.Client(wsdl=wsdl_url, transport=transport)
```

It's annoying to skirt the networking weirdness this pi is always coming up with, but if I figure out how to get it to access IPv6 addresses, I'll add a solution 3.

Comment: that is certainly an option, but instead of introducing an additional dependency, I'd post over at stack overflow for assistance in debugging your actual code. now that you have discounted network reach-ability as a factor, they may be able to help you find the issue preventing the code from being fully portable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure my code is fine. When I run it on my other machines, it works. But this pi is exhibiting weird networking behavior constantly and I'm afraid this is all I can do for it.

Comment: @AlfalfaScout What you can do for it is try to figure out *why* the IPv6 connections time out. Are you deliberately blocking them via nftables? The answer to the original question would then be "remove the rules that block them". What *do* your nftables rules look like? Have you tried disabling them one by one, instead of just all at once?